# how to populate backbone collection from php backend

Tags: javascript, php, rest, backbone.js

I have the backbone code below which shows a list of models on a html page. However the models are created staticly, what modifications do I have to make on the code below to fetch the JSON data and create models based on the data received.

```
    var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: "John Doe",
        age: 27,
        designation: "worker"
    },
    initialize : function(){
        this.on("invalid",function(model,error){
            alert(error);
        });
    },
    validate: function(attrs){
        if(attrs.age < 0){
         return 'Age must be positive,stupid';
        }
        if( ! attrs.name ){
            return 'Name should not be empty';
        }
    },
    work: function(){
        return this.get('name') + ' is a ' + this.get('designation');
    }
});

var PersonCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Person
});

var peopleView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',
    render: function(){
        //filter through all the items in a collections
        //for each, create a new PersonView
        //append it to root element
        this.collection.each(function(person){
            //console.log(person);
            var personView = new PersonView({model:person});
            this.$el.append(personView.render().el);
        },this);
        $(this.$el).appendTo('body');
    }
});

// The view for a Person
var PersonView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName : 'li',
    className : 'person',
    id : 'person-id',
    template: _.template( $('#personTemplate').html() ), 
    initialize : function(){
        _.bindAll(this,'render');
        //console.log(this.model)
        this.render();
    },

    render: function(){

        $(this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()))).appendTo('body');
        return this;
    }
});

var modelperson = new Person;
var viewperson = new PersonView({collection:new PersonCollection(),model : modelperson});

var personCollection = new PersonCollection([
    {
        name: "raghu",
        age:24,
        designation: "CEO"
    },
    {
        name: "shashank",
        age:23,
        designation: "CTO"
    },
    {
        name : "junaid",
        age : 30,
        designation : "UI"
    },
    {
        name: "vishnu",
        age: 23,
        designation: "content developer"
    }

    ]);

var pw = new peopleView({collection: personCollection});
pw.render();
```

html

```
    <script type="text/template" id="personTemplate">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell"><%= name %></div>
        <div class="cell"><%= age %></div>
        <div class="cell"><%= designation %></div>
    </div>
</script>
```

test on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/HVqMs/1/

Comment: From which resource are you guys learning stuff like `$(this.$el)`..?

Comment: *"Backbone doesn't retrieve a list from php"* - this title is totally misleading. You didn't even attempt to retrieve something from `php`.. then how can you blame backbone..? Where's your attempt..?

Comment: php code works fine, it returns JSON data fine. I didn't include it because it's not the problematic code.

Comment: I know.. The title says *"Backbone doesn't retrieve a list"* - but you didn't ask backbone to retrieve anything... You should ask something like *"how to populate backbone collection from php backend"*, and I'm sure you'll get an answer if you google it ;)

Comment: thanks, changed the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean fetching the collection? here is a simple example

```
 var Group = Backbone.Model.extend( {
            urlRoot: Constants.URL_PREFIX+'/api/v1/group',


    });

    var GroupCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend( {
          url: Constants.URL_PREFIX+'/api/v1/group',
          model: Group,
          parse(response){
               this.metaData = new Backbone.Model(response.meta);
               return response.objects;
          }
     });

then to fetch the collection lets call it MyCollection

    var p = new GroupCollection();
    p.fetch().done( function() {
     p.each(function(item){
         console.log(item.get('name'));
     });
    });
```

In my example the json returned is something like this

```
   {
    metaData:{ size:10,limit:10},
    objects:[{name:'pep',id:1},{name:'pep2',id:2}]
    }
```

thats why I override the parse.